# 16.04 LTS upgrade alert- How to handle it?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Today when I logged into my computer I got an update alert saying that I could upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The other options were not now or do not upgrade. If I chose to upgrade will it delete my /home directories and the installed software under /opt and /usr/local ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upgrade will not delete your files and installed software.

It will upgrade all software installed from Ubuntu repositories to new versions.

Please take in account that an upgrade can fail. There is no 100% guarantee it is successful.

If you are not sure, select "not now".